# Sharepoint list item throws null error

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have am iterating through a list of SharePoint list items .
A couple of items do not have data so throw the null  exception.

I used

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xt["ows_LinkTitle"].ToString()))
    {
       Entity.DefectType = xt["ows_LinkTitle"].ToString();    
    }
```

but an error still occurs.

I also tried

```
if(xt["ows_LinkTitle"].ToString()!= null)
   {
       Entity.DefectType = xt["ows_LinkTitle"].ToString();
   }
```

I could put a try catch block around it but I don't want to do it for each and every line.

Is there any way to check the sharepoint item value without throwing an  error.

Comment: what is the type of xt? why do you prefix the field name with `ows_` ? If xt is a list item, you have to pass the field displayname or the field internal name

Comment: @SteveB Please Check [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/50931) for why `ows` prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using explicit cast instead:

```
Entity.DefectType = (string)xt["ows_LinkTitle"];
```

If you want to check for a  `null` before assigning the value try

```
if(xt["ows_LinkTitle"] != null)
```

As `.ToString()` on a `null` is the cause of exception.